# How to allow users to manually edit a label's value in React?

Tags: reactjs, input, onclick

As part of my little React learning project, I have a component that fetches random fantasy names from this NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fantasy-name-generator.

[Click here for the image of the random name generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvJWR.png)

As shown above, every time you click "Randomize!", you get a new name.

Below is the code for the component:

```
import React from "react"

export default function TopSection(props) {
    return (
          <div className="col text-center">
            <input className="form-control" value={props.randomName}/>
            <label>{props.label}</label>
          </div>
    )
}
```

Below is the code for the React App

```
function App() {

const [x,setCharacterName] = React.useState("")
  const elfHero = nameByRace("elf", { gender: "male" })
  function randomNameGenerator(){
    return elfHero
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCharacterName(randomNameGenerator)
  }

  return (

<div className="App ">
      {/* TOP SECTION */}
      <div className="container-flex">
        <div className="row mb-4 gx-3" style={{ margin: "auto" }}>
          <div className="col-12 col-lg-2 bg-light border border-danger rounded mr-3 ">
            <img src={DnDLogo} alt="dnd-logo" className="dndlogo" />

            <TopSection label="CHARACTER NAME"  randomName={elfHero}/>
            <a href="#" class="link-danger" onClick={handleClick}>
              Randomize !
            </a>
          </div>
```

I have two problems:

1. Users accessing the website are able to generate random names every time they click, but cannot edit the input with their own names, or even amend the randomly generated names
2. The randomName function starts as soon as the page loads, when I only want it to start onClick={handleClick}

Thank you!

Comment: do you add useEfect for problem NO.2? you can define a useEffect hook for this and add a dependecy for it . as soon as dependency change load the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Approach 1

To fetch a new name only on click you can move the logic in the `handleClick`.

App

```js
const [characterName, setCharacterName] = useState("");

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const elfHero = nameByRace("elf", { gender: "male" });
  setCharacterName(elfHero);
};

return (
  ...
  <TopSection label="CHARACTER NAME" randomName={characterName} />
  ...
);
```

To let the user modify then value in the input you can add a state. This will, when the randomName changes, update the input accordingly and allow to user to modify its content.

```js
export default function TopSection(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setName(props.randomName);
  },[props.randomName]);

  return (
    <div className="col text-center">
      <input
        className="form-control"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <label>{props.label}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Approach 2

If you want your characterName state just to be in the App you could take an approach like this. Where you give the `TopSection` an onChange handler which will update the `characterName`. The `hanldeClick` logic is still the same a in the first approach.

App

```js
const [characterName, setCharacterName] = useState("");

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setCharacterName(e.target.value);
}

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const elfHero = nameByRace("elf", { gender: "male" });
  setCharacterName(elfHero);
};

return (
  ...
  <TopSection
    label="CHARACTER NAME"
    randomName={characterName}
    handleChange={handleChange}
  />
  ...
);
```

TopSection

```js
export default function TopSection(props) {
  return (
    <div className="col text-center">
      <input
        className="form-control"
        value={props.randomName}
        onChange={props.handleChange}
      />
      <label>{props.label}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much. I still have much to learn on React, and I haven't reached the useEffect section yet. Will get there soon.